# Flutter: 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String', when calling rest api

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart, dart-null-safety

### I would be highly grateful if the answer is in simple terms. I am a beginner.

here is my full project code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nj7Pj7Gzl-xVzzCm-aPRu2H1QUvdjoZB/view?usp=sharing

---

My error is:

```
E/flutter (17497): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter (17497): #0      new Welcome.fromJson (package:getx_5_rest_api/models/product.dart:33:22)
E/flutter (17497): #1      welcomeFromJson.<anonymous closure> (package:getx_5_rest_api/models/product.dart:10:60)
E/flutter (17497): #2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:413:31)
E/flutter (17497): #3      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:342:26)
E/flutter (17497): #4      new List.from (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:41:17)
E/flutter (17497): #5      welcomeFromJson (package:getx_5_rest_api/models/product.dart:10:5)
E/flutter (17497): #6      RemoteServices.fetchProducts (package:getx_5_rest_api/services/remote_service.dart:31:14)
E/flutter (17497): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17497): #7      ProductController.fetchProducts (package:getx_5_rest_api/controllers/product_controller.dart:21:20)
E/flutter (17497): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17497):
```

Comment: Well, the code part related to this issue would be usefull without having to go through the full repo.
About the error, it certainly mean that you try to use a null value somewhere a String is expected.

Answer (score 1):

I found your problem
in the JSON response there is an `image_link` field
but in your code inside the :

```
  factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
  name: json["name"],
  price: json['price'],
  imageLink: json['imageLink'].toString(),
  rating: json['rating']);
```

}

you are trying to get `imageLink` which doesn't exist in the JSON maps List, so it throws null, what exists is `image_link` and they are not the same so the solution is this :
replace the `fromJson` method with this

```
      factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
       name: json["name"],
       price: json['price'],
       imageLink: json['image_link'].toString(),
       rating: json['rating']);
        }
```

it should now find it.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

in line 22 in product model, you probably entered wrong property in the map,
check the response from the API and make sure all the properties match in your
`fromJson()` function

you should use GitHub to share your code, it'll be easier for others to help you when they can just browse the code as easy.